# how do I configure my front end and back-end separately on my deployment server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, next.js

Basically, I was following a course that used a next js frontend and a node js backend API so now I wanted to deploy it to a server but the only way is to run them separately because next js doesn't have an anohter way to connect to the API like create-react-app.

so how is it possible? how do I proxy the requests? and is there's a better way to do it?

Comment: I didn't get it! Your back end deploys on one IP and port, your front deploys on the other one! you have to manage cross-origin if the agents are different! what is the problem exactly? you can access your back end by IP and port. Can't you?

Comment: @Afsane.F Basically I've only one droplet. I want to deploy both frontend and backend in it. run them in different ports and proxy the front end requests to the backend.

Comment: Do you get any errors while setting up ?

Comment: Take a look at this => https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/full-stack-mongodb-react-node-js-express-js-in-one-simple-app-6cc8ed6de274

Comment: @Afsane.F the example you showed uses create-react-app for frontend. I'm using nextjs.